# What is the shape of a Bartles and Jaymes wine cooler called?

Tags: geometry

I am hoping people can see the geometry in this question, but it's simple, describe in simplest terms the geometry of the bottle, and as a bonus, you must NAME the geometric figure if not already named. Something to keep in mind is that I plan to publish the name of this figure, as well as the mathematical descriptions in my autobiography. I will in no way claim the work original to me, and I will fully credit whichever answer is best. Basically, this description will be in a part when I describe the object given to me rather regularly by a playmate's mother. Basically, she used to get us buzzed all the time, and I never found out until after I joined the Army and saw those exact same wine coolers.

I hope this isn't too far off topic, or that it stays open long enough to get one description of the geometric form. Sorry if this is against policy, but I really feel like there are legit mathematics here, given that the shape is somewhat complex to laymen.

Here is a picture of one of the bottles, though I imagine you would have to get your own bottle to make the measurements. Luckily, the things are delicious after you make your measurements.

[image]

Comment: It is some kind of a surface of revolution, but I highly doubt this particular one has an established name. The exact same remarks apply to any object one can make on a potter's wheel or a lathe.